# why I get this error in java?

Tags: java

> Thread [main] (Suspended (The method printf(String, int, int) is
>   undefined for the type PF))

```
import acm.program.*;

public class PF extends ConsoleProgram    
{

        public void run() {

        int x = 4;

        int Y= 17;


        printf("x is %d and Y is %d",x,Y);

    }

}
```

Comment: post your full code ..

Comment: are you using  - `System.out.printf("x is %d and Y is %d",x,Y);` ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider "*Syntax errors are off topic on this site.*" - Did I miss a memo?

Comment: What is `ConsoleProgram`? Is it [this one](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/ConsoleProgram.html)?

Comment: I'm supposed to be using another library to make printf simpler but mark it as an error

Comment: @Turing85 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343565/are-all-syntax-error-questions-off-topic take from that what you will...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to use the `acm.program` library, the problem is that
there is no `printf` method defined anywhere in the library.

Certainly, not in the version 2.0, which is described here: https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/.

You need to stick to using methods that are actually defined by the [`ConsoleProgram` class](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/ConsoleProgram.html).

---

My recommendation would be to not use this library unless you are specifically instructed / required to.  In the long term, you will be better off learning to use the standard Java libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it like this:

```
System.out.printf("x is %d and Y is %d", x, Y);
```

You can't call `printf` static function without it's class name

Or either:

```
System.out.println(String.format("x is %d and Y is %d", x, Y));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.printf`

```
System.out.printf("x is %d and Y is %d",x,Y);
```